# Почему "мушка"?

Tags: этимология

Прицел на оружии называется "мушка". А почему, собственно, он так называется? Аналогия с мухой, но тогда при чем тут муха?
Спасибо заранее

Comment: Вы спрашиваете : при чем тут муха ? Но маленький бугорочек на конце ствола именно муху и напоминает . Латинское musca - муха . Интереснее было бы задать вопрос о происхождении слова МУШКЕТ . Что здесь присутствует : первое огнестрельное ружьё , оснащённое прицелом-мушкой (более ранние фузеи прицелов не имели)? ; или имя мастера-оружейника , сработавшего это ружьё ? Есть , ведь , фамилия МУШКЕТИК (Мушкетик Юрий Михайлович , украинский писатель , лауреат Госпремии СССР) и фамилия МУШКЕТОВ (Мушкетов Иван Васильевич , 1850-1902  , российский геолог , его имя носит ледник Мушкетова на Тянь-Шане) .

Comment: Мушкет, вероятно, из итальянского посредством немецкого, французского и польского. Означало метательный (летающий) снаряд. Связь с мухой есть, но очень косвенная - через латинское musca - муха

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое, что приходит в голову - маленькая, черненькая, глаз останавливает.
Сравните - "шпанская мушка".

Comment: И  присела  на  кончик  ствола.

Answer (score 1):

Статья в словаре Фасмера МУШКА Из франц. mouche "муха; мушка". 
В Новом французско-русском словаре ABBYY Lingvo есть ещё одно из значений "чёрное яблоко (в центре мишени)"